# Laravel create Model and Migration dynamically with dynamic table columns

Tags: laravel

Working on a task where we need to create Model and Migration files programmatically. Also in the **Model** there will be some predefined functions. These functions will be same for all models. The functions are just relations with other Models. I have searched for a few options and found that Laravel has **Stubs** and we can create custom stubs which are great but don't think there is any option to pass params to the stub file when generating it.

In this case, we want to create a model and migration with dynamic columns. May be there is no easy way to do it but in case anyone has done it already, can you please provide me a hint of how you did it.

Trying this laravel package
https://github.com/laravel-shift/blueprint
.It can generate models, migrations, controllers from Yaml file. May be we can create a yaml file dynamically and then publish it.

Thanks

Comment: You can check my package : https://github.com/misterdebug/crud-generator-laravel and read Console/MakeCrud.php (or use the package) :)

Comment: checked your package @misterdebug. I see it generates a migration with columns and models for it. But here the case is different. I want models to have some predefined functions. Like in laravel stubs we can add any functions in file and when file is generated it will already have those functions in it.

Comment: That's not your original question but ok i try an answer you will say me :)

Comment: thank you for your time @misterdebug. Added some more information to the question. Your package creates CRUD. We don't need Views, Controllers, and Requests but just Model and Migration.

Comment: Fork my package and keep only migration and model parts in MakeCrud.php :)

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own command.
for example i wrote a command for generate repository pattern in my projects

```
php artisan make:repository repoName
```

Comment: This is the last option in my list, to write own command to generate files

Answer (score 0):

You can publish stubs

```
php artisan stub:publish
```

Create your custom stub

```
<?php
// stubs/controller.custom.stub
namespace {{ namespace }};
 
use {{ rootNamespace }}Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
/**
 * Hello from the custom controller stub
 */
class {{ class }}
{
    //
}
```

And call it

```
php artisan make:controller --type=custom MyController
```

Watch --type option

Comment: Let's say we created a stub for Model. But we want different column names for each Model. So the $fillable will be different for every created Model.

Comment: I don't see how do this with native stubs sorry :(